# ESLint rule for pure functions in Angular/typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eslint, tslint

Is there any ESLint rule for writing only pure functions in typescript? I wanted to write only pure functions in my code. Does anyone know how do we do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think ESLint is advanced enough to figure out which functions are pure and which aren't.

Comment: @VLAZ technically, you could do something like do not allow `this` to be used inside a function (given that you are, and should not be using, global variables), and no variables that are not defined on the function parameters

Comment: @distante yes. There *is* [a rule somebody made](https://github.com/purely-functional/eslint-plugin-pure) but it's a collection of forbidden things. The author also advises to use it sparingly. It still doesn't ensure the functions are pure. E.g., calling `console.log()` would be impure and the rule wouldn't stop it. If not that, then `alert`. If not that, then `Math.random()`. And so on and so forth. It's not going to ensure total purity.

Comment: @VLAZ I mean, pure does not mean reimplement-implement language-specific functions, but I see your point and the flaw in my comment.

Comment: @distante no, I didn't mean it as these have to be reimplemented. I mean that these are impure operations and using one in a function this makes the function impure. But there is no real way to forbid using them. Nor is it useful. These also *could* be used in an otherwise pure application without "compromising it". Total purity makes for boring applications. Even purely functional applications would want to work with user data or output something to the screen and maybe even have some (pseudo) non-determinism. Pure operations can reign in the impurity.

Answer (score 1):

*Purity Analysis* is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem, and thus cannot be done statically in the general case. There will always be infinitely many functions for which your purity checker can neither prove that they are pure nor that they are impure.

Which means any possible purity checker can only do one of two things:

- Play it safe, and reject any function for which it cannot positively prove that it is pure. This means there are infinitely many pure functions that the purity checker will not allow you to write.
- Accept any function for which it cannot positively prove that it is impure. This means there are infinitely many impure functions that the purity checker will allow you to write.

The proper way to do this, really, is to design the language, the type system, and the libraries from the ground up to be 100% pure. Then, and only then, will you have a chance to automatically check for purity in a sensible way. It is of course still impossible to check in the general case, but designing the language, the type system, and the libraries to be easily checkable helps making the checker more useful.

The trivial case would be to design a language which doesn't allow you to write impure functions in the first place, but such a language would not be terribly useful. As one of the designers of Haskell has said: all that a pure program can do is make the CPU warm. To which someone from the audience responded: making the CPU warm *is* actually a side-effect, too!

Comment: Reachability analysis is also equivalent to solving the halting problem, and yet compilers do it routinely in order to reject provably-unreachable code (and to check that every path in a function reaches a `return` statement). If a tool can detect a certain kind of mistake in almost all practical cases, then it would be useful, even if a tool which detects that kind of mistake in *all* cases is theoretically impossible.